# cannot find symbol class GoogleAnalytics v4

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to implement Google Analytics v4 in my app but after i imported it with gradle using:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

i still get the error

```
cannot find symbol class GoogleAnalytics
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my project i am missing the `Module:app`'s build.gradle file. In order to make the Analytics v4 api work you need to put the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` line in the main app module.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily in the main app module; you need to add to build.gradle file of any module in which you access GoogleAnalytics SDK.